# ArcSDE : Cascading Subtypes in ArcGIS 10/SQL Server

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-desktop, domains

I'm currently creating an ArcSDE DB on an SQL Server. It is designed to complete species survey, with information from the field.

In order to help themselves, they asked me to implement a particular yet logical behavior: in a first field **[Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28biology%29)**, they want a list of related taxa. In a second field, a list of Genera (**[Genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus)**) related to their Order choice. In a third field **[Species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species)** the list related to their Genus choice.

Basically, it is the subtype/domain behavior, but here, the field Genus should be a subtype and a domain at the same time and it's not possible.

So, I thought about implementing this behavior in SQL Server but is it possible? Moreover, will this behavior work directly in ArcMap when working in a editing session on the DB?

Other ideas?
Thanks, Merlin

Comment: I think your "gender" field may be genus or genera.  I would refer to this as hierarchical fields.

Comment: There is an [**ArcGIS Idea**](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004eEQIAY) which relates I think to part of your requirement.  Another part of the requirement can be met with Tool Validation but the last part (as I see it) which I don't yet have an idea for is how to enforce the hierarchy during Attribute editing.

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle your problem using four SQL Server tables:

table 1: Order Lookup (orderid int, OrderName varchar (100))

table 2: Genus Lookup (genusid int, orderid int, GenusName varchar (100))

table 3: Species Lookup (speciesid int, genusid int, SpeciesName varchar (100))

table 4: SurveySpecies (surveyid int, orderid int, genusid int, speciesid int)

Set the Genus Lookup to have the constraint that the orderid foreign key value exists in the Order Lookup Table and is NotNull.
Set the Species Lookup to have the constraint that the genusid foreign key value exists in the Genus Lookup Table and is NotNull.

Populate the lookup tables with everything you will ever run across.  Then you can back populate order and genus in the SurveySpecies table using their related tables (and I would use a python script calling a stored procedure to do that).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a really good answer to this but ...

1. This is an existing **[ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bpI2AAI)** that I would encourage you to vote for because it sounds like your question.
2. Hierarchical field behaviour can be programmed into Geoprocessing tool dialogs using **[Tool Validation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000002v000000)**.
3. There is another ArcGIS Idea (mine) related to this for **[Validation of Hierarchical Fields](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004eEQIAY)**.